# Why am I getting this error after upgrading to Xamarin Forms 2.0?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

For context, I am creating an activity indicator in Xamarin Forms that brings up a new transparent page so it blocks user interaction.

Anyway,

Everything is fine with Xamarin Forms 1.3, but when I upgrade to XF 2.0, I'm getting this issue.

[image]

Here is my code behind for the Xaml

[image]

ModalSpinnerPage
[image]

**From the auto generated class, It looks like Xamarin thinks my ModalSpinnerPage is a member of Xamarin Forms (although its clearly not)**

[image]

Again, my problem is that after the Xamarin forms upgrade, Xamarin thinks my ModalSpinnerPage is a member of Xamarin Forms. Everything is fine before the upgrade though. Any help on this would be awesome. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried adding the fully qualified namespaces to `ModalSpinnerPage` when you inherit from it. Something like: `public partial class ModalPageSpinner : XSpinner.FormsPlugin.ModalSpinnerPage`? Not sure why this would have changed on you though.

Comment: No, I will try this now though thanks

Comment: That unfortunately did not work

Comment: You may be better off submitting a bug report. I know there were bugs around creating base pages and using them in `XAML` before and I have not tried to do it since then, but I was pretty sure that those were fixed by now. Hopefully someone else will find this and give you a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add correct namespaces:

```
<sp:ModalSpinnerClass xmlns:sp="clr-namespace:XSpinner.FormsPlugin;assembly=XSpinner.PutHereCorrectAssemblyPath" /* the rest of properties */>

</sp:ModalSpinnerClass>
```

Here it's working example (using custom pages as a base): [link](https://github.com/daniel-luberda/DLToolkit.Forms.Controls/blob/master/Examples/Pages/FlowListViewExpandPage.xaml)

Answer (score 0):

The following code can work:

```
<ModelSpinner:ModelSpinnerPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:ModelSpinner="clr-namespace:XSpinner.FormsPlugin"
         x:Class="XSpinner.FormsPlugin.ModelPageSpinner">
</ModelSpinner>
```